# Convert array to object delete std class

Tags: php

Hi i need to convert array to object.

So i use :

```
$object = (object)$array;
```

But my problem is i have not the same object. In my current object i have :

```
class Proxies\__CG__\...#1142 (25) { my object...
```

And when i convert array to string i have :

```
class stdClass#1394 (1) {


public ${0} =>


class Proxies\__CG__\...#1142 (25) { my object...
```

How i can to delete the class std and public 0 ?

Comment: Why did you convert the object to an array in the first place?

Comment: What does the array look like? When you convert an array to an object, each index of the array becomes a property name in the object. It sounds like you really want to convert `$array[0]` to an object.

Comment: When you convert an array to an object, it always creates `stdClass`. How is it supposed to know that you want some other class?

Comment: To convert an array to a specific class, you need to write a function that does it.

Comment: Its in symfony, i need to set an object to my entity, and i set the before last parameters.
So for get this before last parameter, i need to get an array of object, i use array_splice($array, -2, 1, true), then i convert this to object

Comment: i have try $object = (object)$test[0]; and indeed its that i want, but its possible to do the same without '[n]' ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you even need `(object)`, if the elements of the array are already objects.

Comment: I can't think of any way to do it without `[n]`. That's how you get specific elements of an array. Why is that a problem?

Comment: I don't know, how many result i can have, this time i can had 3 result, so its $array[2], but next time if i have more than 3 result i can't put $array[2] that will be wrong.

Its for that i want array_slice with -2 in first paramters, and then convert it in object :/.

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: i can in my foreach add an integer who take the number of results, and add -1 when in my array, but if its possible i woulk like do this with other method

Comment: You need to post your original data and the result you're trying to get in the question. It's becoming very unclear what you really need.

Comment: For now i have found a solution, i put [n], i get number of result -1, for get before last result, i will try laster to found a better solution, thanks for your help